# Octave from QT: undefined reference

Tags: c++, qt, linker, embedded, octave

I would like to run **Octave** script from **Qt** GUI application.

Here is `.pro` file:

```
...
win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH +=  c:/Octave/Octave-4.2.1/include/octave-4.2.1/octave

    LIBS        +=  c:/Octave/Octave-4.2.1/lib/octave/4.2.1/liboctave.dll.a \
                    c:/Octave/Octave-4.2.1/lib/octave/4.2.1/liboctinterp.dll.a

    DEPENDPATH  +=  c:/Octave/Octave-4.2.1/bin
}
...
```

Here is `.cpp` file (example is taken from [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/octave.h>
#include <octave/parse.h>
#include <octave/interpreter.h>

int
main (void)
{
  string_vector argv (2);
  argv(0) = "embedded";
  argv(1) = "-q";

  octave_main (2, argv.c_str_vec (), 1);

  octave_idx_type n = 2;
  octave_value_list in;

  for (octave_idx_type i = 0; i < n; i++)
    in(i) = octave_value (5 * (i + 2));

  octave_value_list out = feval ("gcd", in, 1);

  if (out.length () > 0)
    std::cout << "GCD of ["
              << in(0).int_value ()
              << ", "
              << in(1).int_value ()
              << "] is " << out(0).int_value ()
              << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "invalid\n";

  clean_up_and_exit (0);
}
```

When I am trying to compile C++ code from Qt Creator I have the following error:

```
undefined reference to feval(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, octave_value_list const&, int)
```

I also have the following errors from compiler:

```
undefined reference to Array<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::nil_rep()
undefined reference to Array<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::resize_fill_value() const
undefined reference to Array<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::resize_fill_value() const
```

but when I Ctrl+Click on `Array` or `feval` - Qt Creator opens the appropriate files.

I can also compile the example c++ file using the following command from Octave GUI:

```
mkoctfile --link-stand-alone embedded.cc -o embedded
```

What library/path should I add?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: crossposting on the Octave help mailinglist: http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/QT-undefined-reference-to-feval-td4683465.html

Answer (score 2):

If you run mkoctfile on your example from above (I copied it into main.cc) with verbose, you'll see all flags needed:

```
mkoctfile -v --link-stand-alone main.cc 
g++ -std=gnu++11 -c  -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/octave-4.2.0/octave/.. -I/usr/local/include/octave-4.2.0/octave -I/usr/local/include  -pthread -fopenmp -g -O2    main.cc -o main.o
g++ -std=gnu++11  -I/usr/local/include/octave-4.2.0/octave/.. -I/usr/local/include/octave-4.2.0/octave -I/usr/local/include  -pthread -fopenmp -g -O2 -rdynamic  -fPIC     main.o   -L/usr/local/lib/octave/4.2.0 -L/usr/local/lib -loctinterp -loctave
```

Now you have to add these to your QtCreator. (I guess -std=gnu++11 is missing)

Comment: ,here is the output from `mkoctfile -v`:    
`g++ -std=gnu++11 -c -pthread -fopenmp -mieee-fp -g -O2 mbedded.cc -o embedded.o`<br/>
`g++ -std=gnu++11 -pthread -fopenmp -mieee-fp -g -O2 -Wl, -rpath-link, -Wl, --export-all-symbols  -o embedded  embedded.o`

Comment: and from Qt Creator:  
`g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -std=gnu++11 -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG
 -o debug\main.o ..\..\..\moex\octatest\main.cpp`
`g++ -Wl, -subsystem, console -mthreads -o debug\octatest.exe debug/main.o  -LC:\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\lib\octave\4.2.1  C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\lib\octave\4.2.1\liboctave.dll.a  C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\lib\octave\4.2.1\liboctinterp.dll.a`

Comment: I think that the reason of the problem is `--export-all-symbols` flag, but when I set it using `QMAKE_LFLAGS += --export-all-symbols` in my **.pro** file, I get the following error: `g++: error: unrecognized command line option --export-all-symbols`

Comment: Am I right that you don't see an error while compiling but in the linking stage? ("undefined reference to" is typically a linker message). I would ensure that also the order of libs is met (liboctinterp before liboctave). In your second commend it's twisted

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the error that `gcd` function does not exist, or it cannot find reference to it. I don't know about `gcd` function whether it is part of octave or it is your custom defined, but surely it's missing a reference to it.

Comment: I don't think so, because it is a _c-compiler_ error, not the _Octave-interpreter_ error. Function `gcd` does exist in Octave - it computes the greatest common divisor.
But thank you anyway for answering, @i1787